# SF4 + docker : Proxymanager error : syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Tags: docker, symfony, symfony4

I'm encountering a strange error on my branch.
I'm using docker and symfony 4.

Yesterday, i had this error first (that appeared from nowhere) :
[image]

Then, this second error below appears, after me and my colleagues tried to fix the previous issue (i remember we did a composer update, if i'm not wrong, but i'm not quite sure to remember everything ...) 
[image]

And in the configuration.php of ProxyManager :

```
class Configuration
{
    public const DEFAULT_PROXY_NAMESPACE = 'ProxyManagerGeneratedProxy';

    protected ?string $proxiesTargetDir;
    protected string $proxiesNamespace = self::DEFAULT_PROXY_NAMESPACE;
    protected ?GeneratorStrategyInterface $generatorStrategy;
    protected ?AutoloaderInterface $proxyAutoloader;
    protected ?ClassNameInflectorInterface $classNameInflector;
    protected ?SignatureGeneratorInterface $signatureGenerator;
    protected ?SignatureCheckerInterface $signatureChecker;
    protected ?ClassSignatureGeneratorInterface $classSignatureGenerator;

    public function setProxyAutoloader(AutoloaderInterface $proxyAutoloader) : void
    {
        $this->proxyAutoloader = $proxyAutoloader;
    }

    public function getProxyAutoloader() : AutoloaderInterface
    {
        return $this->proxyAutoloader
            ?? $this->proxyAutoloader = new Autoloader(
                new FileLocator($this->getProxiesTargetDir()),
                $this->getClassNameInflector()
            );
    }
```

DockerFile : 
in the DockerFile, we tried also to update the php container from 7.3 to 7.4

```
FROM php:fpm-alpine
```

to

```
 FROM devilbox/php-fpm-7-4:latest
```

but if i do php -v, it's still on php 7.3.
Maybe that's why we have errors above ?

DockerFile now :

```
FROM devilbox/php-fpm-7-4:latest

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
    coreutils \
    php7-fpm \
    php7-apcu \
    php7-ctype \
    php7-curl \
    php7-dom \
    php7-gd \
    php7-iconv \
    php7-imagick \
    php7-json \
    php7-intl \
    php7-mcrypt \
    php7-fileinfo\
    php7-mbstring \
    php7-opcache \
    php7-openssl \
    php7-pdo \
    php7-pdo_mysql \
    php7-mysqli \
    php7-xml \
    php7-zlib \
    php7-phar \
    php7-tokenizer \
    php7-session \
    php7-simplexml \
    php7-xdebug \
    php7-zip \
    php7-xmlwriter \
    make \
    curl
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql # solve "could not find driver" error.
RUN echo "$(curl -sS https://composer.github.io/installer.sig) -" > composer-setup.php.sig \
        && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | tee composer-setup.php | sha384sum -c composer-setup.php.sig \
        && php composer-setup.php && rm composer-setup.php* \
        && chmod +x composer.phar && mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer

CMD ["php-fpm"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

If i checkout on another branch, i've the same problem, always the syntax error.
I'm very new to SF and docker (i did not install myself on the project)
If someone have any idea, it would be great. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: Did you actually re-build the container? The problem is indeed that you're still using 7.3 and typed properties are not supported until 7.4, so make sure to re-build your container if you want to keep using this version of symfony's components.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! 
Yes we needed to rebuild, you are right. 
My colleague changed the image in DockerFile ```FROM php:7.4.2-fpm-alpine```
And executed this command : ```docker-compose build --no-cache --pull```
Everything works, my project is back :D